# K-mean clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I am learning about k-means clustering, I didn't get how clustering will be done if a data point **p** is equidistant from two centroids **c1** and **c2** , to which cluster the point **p** will belong to.

Answer (score 0):

It is not uniquely defined.

If kmeans works, it should not matter much for the result. This is mostly an issue on data where kmeans does not work well, e.g. binary data.

Most implementations will likely prefer the first cluster.